# Procedure sp_Get-- has no parameters and arguments were supplied

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I am getting the error "Procedure sp_Get--  has no parameters and arguments were supplied".
I am calling a simple stored-proc from a CF component.

The Stored proc is as follows

```
GO ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetTest]
  @TestId INT AS BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT T.TestId
        ,T.TestDetail
        ,T.isPassedTest     
    FROM Test T     
   WHERE T.TestId = @TestId
ORDER BY T.TestDetail

END
```

I am calling it in CF8 component/method in the following manner:-

```
<cffunction name="GetTest" returntype="query" access="public" output="false">
  <cfargument name="Test" type="......Test.Test" required="true">
  <cfstoredproc procedure="sp_GetTest" datasource="#variables.datasource#">
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#arguments.Test.GetTestId()#">           
    <cfprocresult name="theTest" resultset="1">
  </cfstoredproc>

  <cfscript>return theTest;</cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Kindly help me in debugging the error!
Thanks

Comment: Please don't use tabs when posting content on SO.  For more info on the markdown supported on SO, see: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Ok i will keep it in mind!
Thanks

Comment: BTW - If you are using MS SQL they recommend you do not use the "sp_" prefix for your stored procedures
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it possible you have two versions of the stored procedure created, one with dbo as owner and with this parameter defined, and the other with the user via which you connect to the database as owner and with this parameter not defined? Can you try using "dbo.sp_GetTest" as the procedure name in CF?

Comment: bulls eye ...it was an typo error from my side in the CFC component.
I corected it